# Count text matches in files based on unique ID

Tags: grep

I have a file which has the following format:

```
    LINK|Grouping_Indicator|ID_Dat|HASH_Akey|HASH_HUKey|
    FALSE|75768163|XY100|c5157cba1b5f20|817f8b50bc9
    FALSE|75768409|XY102|9f3de314a224f2|b686e4760f5
    TRUE|75769393|XY1005|ce0a50207cc86c|f9233c0b8e7
    TRUE|75769885|XY1012|ce0a50207cc86c|ef9eb8ea13f
    TRUE|75723124|XY1111|df0q45677ee89v|gt8qc9fb24g
```

I am trying to count the numbers of TRUE where the HASH_Akey is unique.

I've managed to count the numbers of TRUE in total with the following command:

```
grep -c "TRUE" file.psv
```

However, I am unsure on how to count "TRUE" where the HASH_Akey is unique. 
So the count for "TRUE" from the table above should only return 2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with awk:

```
 awk -F'|' '$1=="TRUE"{a[$(NF-1)]}END{print length(a)}' file
```

with your example, the above one-liner will print `2`

You can also do it with:

```
awk -F'|' '$1=="TRUE"&&!a[$(NF-1)]++' file|wc -l
```

the line is a little bit shorter but it starts another process (`wc`) to do the counting.

Comment: Hi @Kent, 

Thanks for the answer. In your first solution, where do you specify that you're looking for unique values in Column "Hash_Akey" ?

Comment: I guess it's "NF-1"